# Parameters are not set inside NHibernate interceptor

Tags: c#, nhibernate, interceptor

I am trying to use interceptor to add WITH (NO LOCK) for some queries (not for all queries, so ReadUncommitted is not a choice).
Code looks like this:

```
var rawSql = sql.ToString();
if (!rawSql.Contains(IQueryOverExtensions.QueryHintNoLockString))
    return sql;

var noWhere = rawSql.Substring(0, rawSql.IndexOf(WhereKeyword, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
var from = noWhere.Substring(noWhere.IndexOf(FromKeyword, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
var fromWithNoLock = from.Replace("_ ", $"_ {WithNoLock} ");

var sqlWithNoLock = rawSql.Replace(from, fromWithNoLock);

return base.OnPrepareStatement(new SqlString(sqlWithNoLock));
```

Here, I take part form FROM clause to WHERE clause and to each alias add WITH (NO LOCK)

The issue is, that the final SQL's parameters are all "?" and exception is thrown that SQL is not valid. Why parameters are not filled in and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. I had to get number of parameters by calling sql.GetParameterCount() and then replace all question marks with @p0, @p1, @p2, etc.